# find -exec argument doesn't work without a leading space

Tags: git, find, cmder

I'm running Cmder on Windows while trying to run `git log` on all repos in a parent directory.

**UPDATE**
My shell is gitbash version `1.9.4.msysgit.0`

When I run:
`find . -name ".git" -type d -maxdepth 2 -exec echo git --git-dir={} log  ;`

```
git --git-dir= log
git --git-dir= log
git --git-dir= log
```

exec doesn't seem to find the matches from find, but when I run the command with a leading space before the `{}`, the matches are fed to the exec statement, but the syntax is incorrect for git.

`find . -name ".git" -type d -maxdepth 2 -exec echo git --git-dir= {} log  ;`

```
git --git-dir= ./repo1/.git log
git --git-dir= ./repo2/.git log
git --git-dir= ./repo3/.git log
```

Any idea why -exec doesn't handle arguments without a leading space?

Comment: Which shell are you running in Cmder? I'm guessing git bash, but you've not specified... (Cmder is most likely incidental to the question...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what the origin of the issue is, but the following syntax works as expected.

`find . -name ".git" -type d -maxdepth 2 -exec echo git --git-dir="{}" log  ;`

Enclosing the `{}` in double quotes provides the fix I was looking for.

Comment: It's curious because the `find` command doesn't see the double quotes; they're removed by the shell.